# How to read INI file in Linux

Tags: linux, ini

How would you read an INI file using Linux commands? I know in Windows you can use API calls like GetPrivateProfileString..

Example; how to get version under system2:

```
[system1]

version=XYZ

date=123

[system2]

version=ABC

date=985
```

Comment: in which language? Your question is a bit vague...

Comment: Take a look at [`libini`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libini/). It supports most languages, on all platforms.

Comment: basically using script in tiny core linux

Comment: @user1179317 that's not a huge help, which language?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I grab an INI value within a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318809/how-do-i-grab-an-ini-value-within-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the python module [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html):

```py
In [1]: import ConfigParser

In [2]: config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

In [3]: config.read('file.ini')
Out[3]: ['file.ini']

In [4]: config.get('system2','version')
Out[4]: 'ABC'
```

As a script `pass_config.py`:

```py
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('file.ini')
print config.get('system2','version')
```

Run:

```py
$ python pass_config.py
ABC
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at crudini which is a dedicated tool to manipulate ini files from shell

```
version=$(crudini --get example.ini system2 version)
```

Details on usage and download at:
http://www.pixelbeat.org/programs/crudini/