# INI file parsing with KSH

Tags: bash, ksh, ini

I found this bash script here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318901/3834404) that parses an ini file with bash, and it works great. But I'd like to convert this to ksh but get this message when running it with ksh...

> ini_test02.ksh[24]: eval: syntax error at line 7: `end of file' unexpected
>
> ini_test02.ksh[51]: cfg.section.DEFAULT: not found [No such file or directory]

How can you convert this into a ksh script?

Comment: You can refer to the [Ksh manual](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html). Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Not sure on where to begin... Just tried to invoke the script/function using ksh and this is what was returned. Perhaps it's eval and not ksh or is it that function_name.section.section_name is being interpreted by bash as just a function name and ksh is using its object-oriented feature when running the function?

Comment: I've changed the set to >> ini=( ${ini[*]/#\\[/\}$'\n'cfg_section_} ) using underscores instead of periods and get the same results.

Comment: It's atually difficult to convert the function. When run in bash the function creates a function with a name that's not compatible with ksh. e.g. `cfg.section.parameters.ini () {
    database_user=(  user )
    database_version=( 20110611142248 )
}
`. I'm not sure how it would really work with ksh and how you could make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a lot of vars, just parse them one by one. When the values do not contain an equal sign the following might do:

```
keyx="$(grep "^keyx=" my.ini | cut -d= -f2 | sed 's/ *$//')"
```

Or put this in a function and call the function like

```
keyx="$(readini my.ini keyx)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is one of the top search results on google with ksh and INI parsing I'd like to point to https://github.com/wallyhall/shini for INI parsing in KSH.

The only thing that needs to be done is to implement the function(s) __shini_parsed and optional __shini_parsed_section.