# read script properties from configuration file

Tags: bash

I have this batch script:

```
#target environment (this can be DEV/QA/PROD)
targetEnv=DEV 

url=get this from file name env_prop_${DEV}.ini
user=get this from file name env_prop_${DEV}.ini
password=get this from file name env_prop_${DEV}.ini
```

what i would like to do is extract all the the environment configuration into seperate files like:

```
config_DEV.ini   containing:
         url=dev1
         user=dev1
         password=pass1
config_QA.ini   containing:
         url=qa-server
         user=dev
         password=password
config_PROD.ini   containing:
         url=prod-server-01
         user=manager007
         password=*******
```

And then substitute the script variables according to the targetEnv
so for example if targetEnv is QA, variable url will be

```
       url=qa-server
       user=dev
       password=password
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems are you having?

Comment: i found a post with Perl substitution, but we don't have Perl installed.

Comment: Please show the code that you have written so far, with any issues you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
url=$(awk -F "=" '/url/ {print $2}' config_$targetEnv.ini)
user=$(awk -F "=" '/user/ {print $2}' config_$targetEnv.ini)
password=$(awk -F "=" '/password/ {print $2}' config_$targetEnv.ini)
```

Or by sourcing your .ini, if it is formatted the way you wrote:

```
source config_$targetEnv.ini
```

There is useful information here:
[How do I grab an INI value within a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318809/how-do-i-grab-an-ini-value-within-a-shell-script)