# How to export env variable from ini file in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ini

I have ini file(env_var.ini) like below

```
[regionA]
export PROJECT_ID=123
export PROJECT_NAME="project1"

[regionB]
export PROJECT_ID=234
export PROJECT_NAME="project2"
```

First i want to set env variables(project_id,project_name) which is in regionA, after the completion of some operation , i need to set env variables which is in regionB. How i can achieve this using array or loop something.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318809/how-do-i-grab-an-ini-value-within-a-shell-script) should help.

Comment: Sorry, it didnt help , my requirement is quite different

Answer (score 0):

`source <file_name>` will set the variables, but you'll probably need to split the original file, so that it will contain only the block you need;

You can use `csplit`; for instance:

`csplit <file_name> 4` (will split the file into two files in line 4)

now use:

`source <file_name_1>`

and then:

`source <file_name_2>`

[Here's](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds1/csplit.htm) the IBM csplit tutorial...

Goodluck!

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The answer could have more text (how to use csplit with pattern `[...]` without giving a link)  and a warning about the ini-file layout (example layout is OK, don't use spaces around the `=` and use quotes). Even without these changes the answer is nice, so upvoted by me.

Comment: How should OP loop through the regions using these ingredients?