# Shell script reading name value pairs from a file

Tags: bash, shell, key-value

Given a config file, IterVars.txt, of the following format, I need to create a script that will call three of the variables listed.

```
[itervars]
idx1 = 13.0
trigger1 = True
trigger2 = False
startres = 0.123456789
endres = 0.000000123
```

I've tried several key value variable assignment explanations I found here, but it seems all of them have an issue with the spaces in the file, in that it interprets text after the space as a new command.
How do I call these variables in a shell script as:

```
$idx1=13.0
$trigger1=True
$trigger2=False
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I grab an INI value within a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318809/how-do-i-grab-an-ini-value-within-a-shell-script)

Comment: Since the config file is short and you only need three values, it's probably easiest to use the AWK solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318837/4518341). You could functionalize it to reduce code duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You your case and because of the space symbols you can try something like:

```
source <(grep = IterVars.txt|sed -E $'s/[ \t]*=[ \t]*/=/')
```

in your script and you will have variables defined in to the script

Comment: Use this sed command to make sure we handle the whitespace characters even better: `sed -E $'s/[ \t]*=[ \t]*/=/'`.

Comment: You guys rock! This works exactly as needed. Merry Christmas :)