# Increment version number in ini-style file using bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, regexp-replace

I would like to write a bash script to increment all `[metadata]` minor-version numbers contained in files named `setup.cfg`.

The contents of a `setup.cfg` could be:

```
[metadata]
...
version = 1.2.3
...

[<optional-fields>]
...
version=4.5.6
...
```

I would like to *only* increment 1.2.3 to 1.3.3. I want to make sure not to increment the version number of `[<optional-fields>]` and take into account variable/no spacing between `version`, `=`, and `<metadata version number>`.

(edit)

I am able to pull all instances of `setup.cfg` using

`filepath = find | grep "setup.cfg"`

but am uncertain how to isolate `[metadata]`'s version instance. To locate the version instance, I have used:

`[[:space:]]*(?<=\[metadata\])*[[:space:]]*(:?version)[[:space:]]*(:?=)[[:space:]]*`

To replace the old version number with the new one, I was planning on using

`sed -i "s/$old_version/$new_version" $filepath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$  sed -E "/[metadata]/,/[/{s/(\<version ?= ?[^.]*\.)([0-9]+)/echo \1\$((\\2+1))/e;}" setup.cfg
[metadata]
...
version = 1.3.3
...

[<optional-fields>]
...
version=4.5.6
...
```

Comment: I used `find . -name "setup.cfg"  -exec sed -i -E "/\[metadata]/,/\[/{s/(\<version ?= ?[^.]*\.)([0-9]+)/echo \1\$((\\2+1))/e;}" {} \;` and was able to get the result I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to use `bash` `sed` or `grep` for this, as the format is a bit complex for these tools. A simple `python3` program to do this would be like this:

```py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('setup.cfg')
version = config['metadata']['version'].split('.')
version[-1] = str(int(version[-1]) + 1)
config['metadata']['version'] = '.'.join(version)
with open('setup.cfg', 'w') as configfile:
  config.write(configfile)
```

---

Another option is to use the [`crudini`](https://github.com/pixelb/crudini) tool, which is available at least on ubuntu repositories:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IFS=. read -ra arr <<< "$(crudini --get setup.cfg metadata version)"
((arr[2] ++)) 
crudini --set setup.cfg metadata version "$(IFS=.; echo "${arr[*]}")"
```

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25513632/828193) for suggesting the `crudini` tool.

Comment: Using syntax-aware parsers is very much the best-practice approach; this is the Right Way to address the issue.